# Creating a multiple choice quiz python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program to create a file that will contain a multiple choice quiz for people to print or do whatever they want with it. I know how to do the file writing, but am stuck on how to make the choices for the question. The question would ask for the capital of the state, and the choices would give 4 possibilities, with only one being correct. Here is the code:

```
import random

state_capitals = A DICTIONARY of the states and their capitals which I spared you because it was really big :D


file = open(r'''C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\Quiz1CSL.txt''',"w")
#The range(1) is just there as a place holder for later
for x in range(1):

    file.write("Austin's Computer Science State Capitals Quiz\n")

    for x in range(10):
        random_state = random.choice(list(state_capitals.keys()))
        main_typed = "What is the capital of"
        question_mark = "?"
        file.write("\n")
        file.write('{0} {1}{2}\n'.format(main_typed, random_state,question_mark))

file.close()
```

Comment: Maybe better: Use `random.sample()` to get four random capitals and randomly choose one as right answer and show its state to ask for the capital

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed your file-write code, have a look at the marked lines for how to get a sample of 3 + one correct answer from your dict:

```
import random

# testdata "Capitals" as states, "lowercase" as capital ;)
state_capitals = dict([(chr(b).upper(),chr(b)) for b in range(ord("a"),ord("z")+1)])

for x in range(10):
    random_state = random.choice(list(state_capitals.keys()))
    main_typed = "What is the capital of"
    question_mark = "?"

    choices = sorted( random.sample([state_capitals[x] for x in state_capitals if x != random_state],3) + [state_capitals[random_state]])
    # random.samples(list,n) gives you n unique random values from list
    # and I add in the "correct" one, by sorting them you have a uniform
    # a to z order that lets the correct one vanish into the others.

    print('{0} {1}{2}'.format(main_typed, random_state,question_mark))
    print('Choices: ' + ",".join(choices))
```

With [Michael Butchers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987358/michael-butscher) excellent suggestion this boils down to:

```
for x in range(10):
    choices = random.sample(list(state_capitals),4) 
    random_state = random.choice(choices)
    main_typed = "What is the capital of"
    question_mark = "?"

    print('{0} {1}{2}'.format(main_typed, random_state,question_mark))
    print('Choices: ' + ",".join([state_capitals[x] for x in choices]))
```

Output:

```
What is the capital of F?
Choices: f,i,p,r
What is the capital of P?
Choices: h,j,p,w
What is the capital of J?
Choices: g,i,j,v
What is the capital of B?
Choices: b,n,s,w
What is the capital of C?
Choices: c,p,s,z
What is the capital of U?
Choices: g,l,u,w
What is the capital of C?
Choices: c,g,h,t
What is the capital of B?
Choices: b,o,y,z
What is the capital of R?
Choices: e,k,r,w
What is the capital of P?
Choices: b,p,x,z
```

Comment: Random.sample(list(state_capitals),4) doesn't seem to work, it returns this: choices = random.sample(list(state_capitals), 4)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sample'

Comment: @leo_someone dont name your variables after modules. you have a string variable called random that shadows the module `random` so you cant acces its methods anymore. also do not name anything `list`, `dict` or any other module/inbuild name: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Comment: @leo_someone glad it helped, feel free to upvote/mark as answer